# React native pdf to image

Tags: react-native, image, pdf, pdf-conversion

So, I want to convert pdf pages into images in react native without compromising quality is there any best solution other than react-native-pdf-thumbnail.

Comment: define "the best way".

Comment: without compromising quality.

Comment: what about this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-to-image

Comment: @LukaDumančić 
  Have you used that? because it is old and not maintained.

Comment: I haven't. If you can't find a library for this, you can use some external APIs for this.

Comment: can you please suggest anyone?